# Some events dont work in Winform in C#

Tags: c#, events, static

I am using YoutubeExtractor's dll.. videoDownloader_ProgressChanged and videoDownloader_DownloadFinished events are working in console application but in winform, it doesnt work.. I dont understand why..

```
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


         string link = textBox1.Text;
         start(link);

    }

    static void start(string link)
    {
        IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videoInfos = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(link);

        DownloadVideo(videoInfos);
    }

    private static void DownloadVideo(IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videoInfos)
    {
        VideoInfo video = videoInfos
            .First(info => info.VideoFormat == VideoFormat.Standard360);

        var videoDownloader = new VideoDownloader(video, Path.Combine("C:/Downloads", video.Title + video.VideoExtension));
        videoDownloader.DownloadFinished += new EventHandler(videoDownloader_DownloadFinished);

        videoDownloader.ProgressChanged += new EventHandler<ProgressEventArgs>(videoDownloader_ProgressChanged);
        videoDownloader.Execute();
    }

    static void videoDownloader_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
    {
                   //some code..
    }

    static void videoDownloader_DownloadFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //some code..

    }
```

my second question is, I want to access a form control in a static videoDownloader_ProgressChanged event. e.ProgressPercentage paramter gives me percent of video downloaded. I want to show it in label. But I cant access label because of static event.. I tried to use delegate but nothing changed..

Comment: Calling a method like 'videoDownloader.Execute()' in a GUI event handler is probably a very bad idea.  What does it do and, more importantly, how long does it take?  If it takes a human-noticeable amount of time, thread it off.  You should then BeginInvoke() in the changed/finished handlers.

Comment: It is very unclear what kind of component you are using.  You'll need to contact the owner or author for support.

Comment: @Likurg, actually I dont know why he used statics method. But when I rewrite it with nonstatic methods, it doesnt work..

Comment: @HansPassant, what is the problem ?

Comment: Your question boils down to "I use a frooble widget and it doesn't work right.  What's wrong with it?"  We don't know what a frooble is, that's the problem.

Comment: @HansPassant, Hey calm down :) I just asked why it works in console and not works in winapp.. and here is source code of dll https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor  thank you

Comment: Where are the events wired up?  Through the designer or somewhere else in the code?  Is the `videoDownloader` a control on the form?  What gets sent for `sender` in the static event handler?

Comment: @GuthMD, I dont have any control on the form.. just code.. sender sents  'sender = {YoutubeExtractor.VideoDownloader}' its a class.. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please modify both Start() and DownloadVideo() routines to instance methods. Remove 'static' keyword from them and event handlers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thread off 'videoDownloader.Execute()' and BeginInvoke() in the changed/finished handlers.

Don't call methods that take forever, (in computer terms), in GUI event handlers. If it takes more than about 50ms, thread it off.  Any net thingy, eg. something with 'YouTube' in it, will take longer than that just to establish a connection!

Comment: it takes about 10 seconds to download a video. I know that its not a good code.. and I dont understand clearly what you wrote.. I must use threads? and what about events ? thank you

Comment: You should not make long-running and/or blocking calls in a GUI event-handler.  If you do so, the GUI thread will be unable to process messages posted to its input queue until the call is over and the event-handler can exit.  That means no handling for keyboard messages, mouse messages, repaint messages etc.  You can change the visual properties of progress bars etc. all you want - nothing will be rendered on the display until the blocked-up event-handler can exit.  What about events? - well, for events to work, some thread must be available to call them.

Comment: okay thnk you very much for your ansewer.. now its clear.. I am going to use thread.. or do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Try BackgroundWorker.  The events will be called in the BackgroundWorker context and so will need BeginInvoke()ing to the GUI thread to update stuff.